# Add container under body directly in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, containers

In Magento 2, I want add a new container `right.sidebar` **under `<body>` directly**, not under `content` container. Then move the block `catalog.product.related` to the new container. I write the codes below in my custom `catalog_product_view.xml`, but it doesn't work. Thanks for any advice :)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <container name="right.sidebar" />
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="right.sidebar" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In container tag there you must have a attribute

> htmlTag

So you XML should be like :

`<container name="right.sidebar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="right-sidebar"  />`

You can use htmlClass for applying any CSS class so that you can apply your css to it and before/after attribute to define it's place in page.

> Note : class name should not contain dot(.) or #  because it's css and is selectors.

I have tested your code with my modification (after adding htmlTag attribute) it's working fine.